# Insert new rows based on the number of duplicates found in a table and populate these rows with the duplicate row data

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below table on Sheet2

[image: Table1]

I have the below range on Sheet1

[image: Range]

Item No. & Qty is data that is manually inserted. Description, Bin Code and UOM are found via VLOOKUP from Table1.

I need to auto insert rows underneath the item numbers that contain duplicates in Table1 and populate these newly inserted rows with the duplicate data.

The end goals is for me to be able to be given a set of item numbers and their quantities and be able to run a piece of code that inserts and populates the duplicate rows (however many there are) from Table1. (This, will of course, exclude the quantity column, as this is manually inserted and will need to be left blank on the new rows)

My knowledge is limited so I have got as far as calculating the number of duplicates contained in Table1 and then the number of new rows that will need to be inserted. I do not know where to go from here...

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iACTJ.png)

Comment: Here are a few things to help you on your way: **1** Loop backwards with a for loop, i.e. `For i = lastRow To 2` . That way, adding rows won't disrupt the next row. **2** As for getting the "however many there are", use `.Find` see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find However, you probably won't want to replace the Item No. from your table (like in the example in the link) so you'll have to use an `If c.address = firstAddress Then Set c = Nothing` or something similar.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the table in Sheet 2 after your requirement is applied (the result)?

Comment: Of course, although Sheet 1 is where the changes will be made. Sheet 2 is where the data is pulled from. I have added the result to the bottom of the post - it will only allow me to post links, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly....

Before running the sub
[image]

Expected result :
In sheet1, there will be two more AAA item with bin a1 and a3, and one more DDD item with bin d2. Something like the image below: 
[image]

Please note, that in sheet2 there is GGG item. But since the code just check what is in sheet1 against what is in sheet2, it doesn't check what is in Sheet2 against what is in Sheet1, so GGG item is ignored. GGG item is not added to sheet1.

> I need to auto insert rows underneath the item numbers

If the images above is similar with your case and if you don't mind that the code is not inserting row, but adding data to the cell below the last row with data (then sorting it) ... maybe you want to have a look the code below :

```
Sub test()
Dim rgS1 As Range: Dim rgS2 As Range: Dim c1 As Range: Dim c2 As Range
Dim cd As String: Dim concat As String

'set data range in column A of both sheets as rgS1 and rgS2 variable
With Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rgS1 = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

With Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rgS2 = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

'loop to each cell in rgS1 as c1 variable
'get the bin code as cd variable
'concatenate c1 value and the cd as concat variable
'check, if the cd is found in rgS2
'get the cells in sheet2 which contain the c1 value as rg variable
'then loop to each cell in rg as c2 variable
'if the looped cell value & the looped cell.offset(0,1) value <> concat
'write the needed value from sheet2 to sheet1

For Each c1 In rgS1
cd = c1.Offset(0, 2).Value: concat = c1.Value & cd
    If Not rgS2.Offset(0, 1).Find(cd, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        With rgS2
            .Replace c1.Value, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
            Set rg = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical)
            .Replace True, c1.Value, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        End With
        
        For Each c2 In rg
            If c2.Value & c2.Offset(0, 1).Value <> concat Then
                With rgS1.End(xlDown)
                    .Offset(1, 0).Value = c2.Value
                    .Offset(1, 1).Value = c2.Offset(0, 3).Value
                    .Offset(1, 2).Value = c2.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    .Offset(1, 4).Value = c2.Offset(0, 2).Value
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

'sort the table in sheet1 based on ITEM and BIN
With Sheets("Sheet1").Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
     .Header = xlYes
     .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will test and get my head around this soon. Is this solution specific to this example or would it still produce the same results if I had a larger set of data with multiple duplicates?

Comment: The code should apply although the data is larger as long as the same background logic applied which is : loop to check if in sheet1 the value of Sh1Cell_A(n) exist in columns A of sheet2. If the value exist (say the value is found in cell A(x) sheet2), then loop to check if the value of cell Sh1Cell_B(n) also exist in Sh2Cell_D(x). If yes, do nothing, if no, copy value of Sh2Cell_A(x) to the last row (nth row) sheet1 col_A, copy Sh2Cell_D(x) value to sheet1 that nth row col_b, copy Sh2Cell_B(x) value to sheet1 that nth row col_C and copy Sh2Cell_C(x) value to sheet1 that nth row col_E.

Comment: The code does not seem to work as expected. 'sort the table in sheet1 based on ITEM and BIN' does what it says but the rest does not effect the worksheets at all. Is there something I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to make a new workbook, have sheet1 and sheet2 with data just like in the image before running the sub. Copy the code in this workbook then step run into the code (press F8 on the keyboard) ?

Comment: Thanks, I have it working now on a new workbook now but the trouble is, my sheet1 range actually begins at A15 and not A2 as there is other data etc above. I have tried what I deemed as 'obvious' to change the range but it does not work, what do you suggest?

Comment: If in sheet1 starting A15 to down whatever row is the data to be checked, then change the rgS1 to `Set rgS1 = .Range("A15", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`. The same thing with sheet2, if the ITEM column in sheet2 is not starting from A2, then change it the Set rgS2. And also the header on sheet1 and sheet2 must be same with my image of sheet1 and sheet2.